# Why calling Python script from setup.py invokes Python shell instead?

Tags: python, subprocess, pip, easy-install

I try to call a Python script from setup.py during installation, using a custom install:

```
class CustomInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)

        ...

        p = subprocess.Popen(
            [sys.executable, 'demo_package/deploy_database.py'],
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            cwd=os.path.join(self.install_lib, 'demo_package'))

        out, err = p.communicate()

setup(..., cmdclass=dict(install=CustomInstall))
```

When deploying the package on a Ubuntu machine, the process, instead of executing deploy_database.py, shows nothing. When I stop it manually with Ctrl+C, the output seems to indicate that instead of actually running deploy_database.py, it simply starts Python:

```
^CDownloading/unpacking PypiPackagesMonitoring
  Downloading demo-1.0.64.zip  
  Running setup.py egg_info for package demo

Installing collected packages: demo
  Running setup.py install for demo

    Python 3.3.2+ (default, Oct  9 2013, 14:50:09)
    [GCC 4.8.1 on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Cleaning up...
Operation cancelled by the user
Storing complete log in /home/.../.pip/pip.log
```

What is wrong in the way I call a Python script? How should I do it instead?

Comment: Or you could probably use `execfile`.

Comment: `shell=True` *ought* to imply that you *need* a feature that *cannot* be expressed as a simple sequence of strings, i.e. when using `shell=True` you must use a single string that represents the whole *shell command*(which is *not* simply calling an external program, but includes some shell features such as pipes/redirection/calling a built-in etc.). Otherwise you *should* use `shell=False` and you can represent the program to execute and its arguments in the same format of `sys.argv`. Mixing the two methods results in this strange results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shell=True` is not needed with `[sys.executable, 'demo_package/deploy_database.py']`, and causes problems. The way you're doing it (if you omit `shell=True`) is the preferred way, because it bypasses the shell.

`shell=True` makes Popen hand over the passed command to a shell (e.g. `/bin/bash`, depending on the shell configured for the current user). Only the first command passed in the list is executed, the other elements of the list are passed as arguments to the shell itself (from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)):

> On Unix with shell=True […] If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself.

`shell=True` is a bit dangerous, but also useful in some cases. See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for details.